# LinkedIn Company Insider Widget

Tags: widget, linkedin-api

Anyone got the Company Insider LinkedIn widget to work.

http://developer.linkedin.com/community/widgets

The examples on the above page only the Microsoft and IBM works - the Apple one appears to have the same issues that I am having - this is without being logged in.

The issues being:

- It shows 0 people
- The link to the company doesn't work (apparently Apple doesn't exist!)

Any ideas to get the same information without using this widget would also be helpful.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: yes sorry - that is the issue that it shows 0 people - why would it only show 0 for Apple? Also the link to the company doesn't work.

Comment: I guess it's failing to find the company, then - there's a '-1' in the ID in the URL. There's lots of people complaining about the same issue http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1071#comments and "yeah, we're not going to change it" comments from the LinkedIn devs :-/

Comment: @Rup - yes I saw that - was hoping I might have some luck here with workarounds/solutions - thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately the company name is fed into the iframe generator URL as-is - I was hoping there was something in the script we could override to drop in a company ID but can't see one and attempts to try a companyId parameter or use the ID for the name didn't work. Here's the URL: http://www.linkedin.com/companyInsider?data&companyName=Apple&backgroundColor=FFFFFF&titleBackgroundColor=FFFFFF&textColor=4c4c4c&trackinginfo=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.linkedin.com%2Fcommunity%2Fwidgets&isPopup=yes

Comment: It appears to work if you use the short company name that LinkedIn use in their URLs, e.g. "apple-inc". However it then displays that on the form insetad of the full name :-/